# How can I determine if my rails is in the development environment and not the test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, environment

I have some code that needs to run only if the rails app is in the development environment (i.e. $ rails server) but not in the test environment (i.e. $ rake test).

When I try

```
if Rails.env.development?
    dont run me during testing
end
```

the code gets executed regardless of which environment I am in. I've even tried:

```
if Rails.env.development? and not Rails.env.test?
    NO, REALLY, DONT RUN ME DURING TESTING
end
```

but no love.

What should I be doing instead?

Comment: This code should work. Have you tried outputting `Rails.env` inside that block to see what environment Rails thinks it's using?

Comment: I think it could be the "and not" bits.. that is not the same as && !  That is me guessing.. did you find a solution?

Comment: I never found a solution. For whatever reason, rails runs its initializers twice (see comment below). I've since abandoned rails.

Answer (score 160):

It looks like you're calling it correctly. Perhaps the problem is that the environment is named differently somewhere. Try in the console:

```
> Rails.env
=> "development"
> Rails.env.development?
=> true
> Rails.env.test?
=> false
```

...to confirm that the environment is what you think it is.

Comment: Ok, I've created an initializer which merely 'puts Rails.env'. The result is that $ rails server gives 'development', while $ rake test gives both 'development' and 'test'. This suggests to me that rails is runnning my initializer twice during $ rake test.

Comment: You can also open the console in a specific environment, e.g. `RAILS_ENV=test rails console`.

Comment: don't worry if you've not installed pry in your app. it works in simple console also